# set-top box programming

Tags: television

I want to know how can one get started with programming for set top boxes? Will all the hype about Apple TV, Google TV and all, I have not seen any directions on how one can get started with writing applications for these devices?

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start google tv [here](https://developers.google.com/tv/)

For Apple TV check ths SDK [here](http://alanquatermain.net/brdevkit/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a link to sign-up for the Android SDK on [this](http://www.google.com/tv/faq/) page.